# Resolving a JDWP Error 502

Tags: java, jdi, jdwp

I am working on a JDI project and connecting it to a tomcat server. If I have a bug in my code that causes my project to fail, while attached to the tomcat server, I will start to get `com.sun.jdi.InternalException: Unexpected JDWP Error: 502` when invoking. The only way I have found to resolve this is restarting my JDI project and the tomcat server. Is there another method of resolving a JDWP code 502 programmatically? Based on the info in the below article, is it possible to terminate all previously invoked methods on a virtual machine after connecting to it?

According to this article [JDPW Error List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/jpda/jdwp/jdwp-protocol.html#JDWP_Error) is defined as:

`ALREADY_INVOKING 502 Previous invoke not complete.`